# Android updating Activity when onBackPressed is called on another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

As the title suggests, my aim is to update some variables on one `Activity` "`MainActivity`" when another `Activity`"`AddActivity`" is being back pressed. At the moment, the only way I can update variables on `MainActivity` is when I create a new instance of it, which I don't want to do. I want the update of the variables to happen on a `MainActivity` which is already instantiated. Some snippets of the code are below:

```
public class AddActivity extends MainActivity { 
    ....
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        updateMain();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ....    
    // This gets executed when the Activity gets created
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("tag", "main onstart");
        updateMain();
    }

    protected void updateMain() {    
        DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(this);
        dba.open();
        ....
        double cost = dba.getCost();
        String costString = String.valueOf(cost);
        textView.setText(costString);
        dba.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: is there any error at you logcat or what is the problem

Comment: I'll emulate it again and observe LogCat.

Comment: LogCat didn't show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Are you sure It is necessary? You may want to update your activity in onResume method. Or you may want to use [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). It will handle updating UI for you.

Comment: Tried onResume(), didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

the AddActivity extends MainActivity, so when you call updateMain() in AddActivity, it will call the AddActivity's updateMain but not MainActivity's, so it will take no effect.

```
public class AddActivity extends MainActivity { 
    ....
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        updateMain();// it is this.updateMain, while 'this' here means a AddActivity instance.
    }
}
```

i think the AddActivity extends MainActivity is not a must(maybe...). you can write the data to SharePreference, ant then read it from you MainActivty.

Comment: Alright, I will test to see if MainActivity is necessary (design decision by a team member). Will report soon.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of an epiphany thanks to @EricHua23, I didn't need to extend `MainActivity` and that `updateMain()` was calling `AddActivity`'s `updateMain()`. So what I did was made a custom `Activity` `RootActivity` class which stores the `MainActivity` instance to a variable by Overriding `onCreate()`, and I simply make all the classes extend `RootActivity`. This way, I can access `MainActivity`through this variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can update a Main activity from add activity by using Handler inside AddActivity and on Main Activities onBackpressed send empty message by using handler and inside of AddActivity Handler update variable which you want ,
define handler in Application Class and make setter and getter method of it and use it in mainActivity and AddActivity.